# Possible vertex degrees of a tree $T$

Tags: graph-theory

A tree $T$ has $8$ vertices, at least two of which have degree $3$.
What are the possible degree sequences of $T$?

This is my attempt:
Let the vertices be $v_1,\ldots, v_8$.
By Handshaking Lemma,
$$\sum_{k=1}^8 \mathrm{deg}(v_k) =14$$

Let $\mathrm{deg}(v_k) = x_k$.
So $$x_1 + \ldots + x_8 = 14$$

Since T is a tree, at least one vertex has degree $1$.
Let $v_2,v_3$ be the two vertices that must be at least degree $3$
So we want the solutions to
$$x_1 + \ldots + x_8 = 14$$
where $x_1 = 1, x_2,x_3 \geq 3, x_4,\ldots,x_8 \geq 1$.

Let $y_2 = x_2 - 3, y_3 = x_3 - 3$
and $y_k = x_k - 1$ for $k=4,5,\ldots,8$.

So
$$y_2 + \ldots + y_8 = 3$$
where $y_\ell \geq 0$
which has $\binom{10}7 = 120$ solutions...
It seems that there should be much less solutions here.
Where did I go wrong here and how would I actually find the degree sequences?

Comment: Show $6\le x_2+x_3\le8$. Then there aren't many possibilities for $\{\,x_2,x_3\,\}$, and for each possibility you can work out the possibilities for the other $x_i$.

Comment: You have more than one vertex of degree $1$...

Comment: Also, you say "at least two have degree $3$", meaning $x_2,x_3=3$. But you then write $x_2,x_3\geq 3$ which would mean "two have degree at least $3$". Which one is it?

Comment: Oops, I should've written $x_2,x_3 = 3$ then, the question is written as from my book

Comment: Any luck following my suggestion, Natash1?

Comment: I've gotten it. Thanks :)

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.